# Is it possible to cite a webpage using amsrefs?

Tags: bibliographies, amsrefs

I'm (becoming) familiar with amsrefs' limited bibliography entry types and would like to know how one could add an entry type for citing a web page.

According to the [documentation](ftp://ftp.ams.org/ams/doc/amsrefs/amsrefs.pdf-hold) for the package (at the bottom of page 14) , I just need to use the `\BibSpec` command, but I'm not entirely certain of the details in doing so.  For example, where would I include this command?  And what does the interior formatting look like for a webpage entry?

A second question is whether I'm better off "creating" a webpage entry by abusing the `article` entry.  If so, what would that look like?

It's definitely too bad that there's no support for the `misc` entry type in amsrefs.  I'm refusing to switch to BibTeX at this point on a simple bet with a mate, which I may lose very soon.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The amsrefs documentation also describes a "webpage" entry type (top of page 11 at ftp://ftp.ams.org/ams/amsrefs/amsrdoc.pdf), although it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @KevinO'Bryant The `webpage` entry type seems to work now. I have now provided an answer to this question with this option.

Comment: "It's definitely too bad that there's no support for the `misc` entry type in amsrefs." In AMSRefs, the `misc` entry type is an alias for the `book` entry type, so it's not exactly analogous to the usage in BibTeX.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`amsref` offers the eprint field that you can use inside of, for example, the `article` entry type to introduce some web page. Another possibility is to define a fresh new bib entry type (which approach to use will depend on the specific intended ussage). In the following example code I illustrate both approaches.

I defined a new bib entry type (called `webpage`)  using `\BibSpec`; this type recognizes the fields `author`, `title`, `year`, `myurl` and `note`. The new field `myurl` calls `\myurl` which was defined simply to typeset its argument using the `\url` command from the `url` package.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[lite]{amsrefs}
\usepackage{url}

\DefineSimpleKey{bib}{myurl}

\newcommand\myurl[1]{\url{#1}}

\BibSpec{webpage}{%
  +{}{\PrintAuthors} {author}
  +{,}{ \textit} {title}
  +{}{ \parenthesize} {date}
  +{,}{ \myurl} {myurl}
  +{,}{ } {note}
  +{.}{ } {transition}
}

\begin{document}

\title{The Title}
\author{The Author}

\maketitle

\begin{bibdiv}
\begin{biblist}
\bib{yellowmonster}{book}{
   author={Bousfield, A.K.},
   author={Kan, D.M.},
   title={Homotopy Limits, Completions and Localizations},
   date={1972},
   series={Lecture Notes in Mathematics},
   volume={304},
   publisher={Springer-Verlag},
   address={Berlin-New York},
  eprint={dfgsdfgfs}
 }

\bib{texsx}{webpage}{
  author={The Author},
  title={The Title},
  date={2012},
  myurl={http://www.stackexchange.com/},
  note={Some additional information}
}

\bib{serre:shfs}{article}{
   author={Serre, Jean-Pierre},
   title={Homologie Singuli\`ere des Espaces Fibr\'es.  Applications},
   date={1951},
   eprint={http://www.some.site.com/},
   note={Some additional information}
 }
\end{biblist}
\end{bibdiv}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Citations to websites usually distinguish between date (the date the site was last changed, when the author viewed it) and the access date (the date the author last saw the site).

Answer (score 2):

AMSRefs already offers the `webpage` bibliography entry type for this purpose. It takes the fields `author`, `title`, `subtitle`, `date`, `url`, `accessdate` and `note`.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsrefs}

\begin{document}

\begin{bibdiv}
\begin{biblist}

\raggedright

\bib{your-cite-key}{webpage}{
    author={tentaclenorm},
    title={Is it possible to cite a webpage using amsrefs?},
    subtitle={},
    date={2012-08-05},
    url={https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/65972/},
    accessdate={2021-06-11},
    note={},
}

\end{bibdiv}
\end{biblist}

\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot of the output of the above MCVE.]